# UITableView crashes on scroll when using XML plist

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xml-serialization, plist

i've been reading for hours, searched apple's doc, stackoverflow, can't understand what i'm doing wrong....

when i use this data from a XML plist on my UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrayofstrings"
                                                             ofType:@"plist"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSString *error;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;

        myArray = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:myData
                                                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                 format:&format
                                                       errorDescription:&error];
    }
```

my tableview shows the first visible rows just fine but crashes when trying to scroll.

it doesn't happen when instead of the XML data i use something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

        myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"thing1", @"thing2", @"thing3", @"thing4", @"thing5",@"thing6", @"thing7", @"thing8", @"thing9", @"thing10", 
            @"thing11",@"thing12", @"thing13", @"thing14", nil];

        }
```

this way the tableview scrolls just fine. what's my problem?! Is the plist conversion to array supposed to be in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrayofstrings"
                                                             ofType:@"plist"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSString *error;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;

        myArray = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:myData
                                                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                 format:&format
                                                       errorDescription:&error] retain];
    }
```

The return value from `propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription` is `autorelease`d. Make sure you call retain so it doesn't get released out from under you at the end of the current run loop.

The second method works because creating the `NSArray` with `alloc/init` leaves the array with a retain count of 1.

Comment: i bow to your coding power! you were absolutely right, i should know better the methods i use.... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first case your call to `[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:` returns an NSArray with no retain count on it (note the method doesn't have alloc, new, or copy in the name) - and then you don't retain this NSArray. Hence, the array is getting deallocated shortly after, and your code crashes trying to access garbage memory.

In the second case, you are making an NSArray using `alloc` - this returns an NSArray with a retain count of 1, which means it isn't deallocated (until a release gets called at some point).

To fix this, in your first case you want to assign the array as follows:

```
self.myArray = ...
```

The `self.` is the crucial part here (assuming you have declared the myArray property as `retain`).

There's plenty of resources and [blog posts](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/) available concerning memory management.